# Is viral keratitis contagious?

Tags: eye, disease-transmission, disease, virus

Is viral keratitis contagious? I'm asking, as I'm not getting any authentic material on the net.

Comment: Welcome to Health. I've gone ahead and edited your question to make it on-topic. Personal diagnosis is considered odd-topic here, and this your background information unneeded. If you disagree with my edit, please [edit] the question yourself or rollback my edit. Good question though!